# Trouble writing sparse matrix to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy, export-to-csv

I'm a newbie to Python, and I'm trying to write the data in a matrix to a CSV file.  The variable is defined as:

```
(Pdb) trainFeatures
<1562936x312116 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 43753231 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I have a line of code:

```
numpy.savetxt("feature_train.csv", trainFeatures, delimiter=',')
```

When I run that line, I get an error message:

```
ncol = X.shape[1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I'm sure the matrix is somehow not in the right format, but I don't know how to get it so.  Can anyone point out what I need to do here?

Comment: Have you tried trainFeatures.todense()?

Comment: That does work, but the resulting matrix can't be placed in memory because of the sheer size.  Make sure you answer the question so you can get the credit.

Comment: A sparse matrix keeps its data in numpy arrays, but is not a numpy array itself.  So the (plain vanilla) `numpy.savetxt` function cannot save it.  You either have to find a sparse knowledgeable `savetxt` in `scipy`, or save the components of the matrix yourself.  `scipy.io` can save spare matrixes in MATLAB compatible files.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, to complete the process, the answer to the original question is to use the todense() method turn trainFeatures into a format that savetxt() recognizes. But to make a further comment on the lack of memory, the obvious solution would be to use the getrow() method and iterate through all rows and write each row to the file individually, rather than trying to do the whole matrix in one go.